# Calculate average of last 3 non holiday weekdays

Tags: r

I have a dataframe for number of profile hits with date time, week, weekday across various categories.

For sample data refer below (Input Data). What I am looking for is to output a dataframe with average of last 3 weekdays of non holiday weeks from Sunday to Saturday across all categories.

As you can see in the below required output, none of the data from holiday week is considered. Is there any easy way of achieving this without use of loops? If yes how can we do this?

#### required output:

```
CAT  Day  Avg
A    SUN  =(1 + 3+99) /3
A    MON  =(6+67+ 45) /3
A    TUE  = (2+ 53+ 68)/3
A    WED
A    THU
A    FRI
A    SAT
```

#### Input data:

```
CAT  DATE       WEEJ    DAY  Hits   Holiday Week
A   9/3/2016    2016-35 SAT  58     No
A   9/2/2016    2016-35 FRI  9      No
A   9/1/2016    2016-35 THU  20     No
A   8/31/2016   2016-35 WED  92     No
A   8/30/2016   2016-35 TUE  2      No
A   8/29/2016   2016-35 MON  6      No
A   8/28/2016   2016-35 SUN  1      No
A   8/27/2016   2016-34 SAT  58     Yes
A   8/26/2016   2016-34 FRI  56     Yes
A   8/25/2016   2016-34 THU  40     Yes
A   8/24/2016   2016-34 WED  42     Yes
A   8/23/2016   2016-34 TUE  59     Yes
A   8/22/2016   2016-34 MON  21     Yes
A   8/21/2016   2016-34 SUN  98     Yes
A   8/20/2016   2016-33 Sat  2      No
A   8/19/2016   2016-33 FRI  85     No
A   8/18/2016   2016-33 THU  29     No
A   8/17/2016   2016-33 WED  37     No
A   8/16/2016   2016-33 TUE  53     No
A   8/15/2016   2016-33 MON  67     No
A   8/14/2016   2016-33 SUN  3      No
A   8/13/2016   2016-32 SAT  35     No
A   8/12/2016   2016-32 FRI  24     No
A   8/11/2016   2016-32 THU  94     No
A   8/10/2016   2016-32 WED  81     No
A   8/9/2016    2016-32 TUE  68     No
A   8/8/2016    2016-32 MON  45     No
A   8/7/2016    2016-32 SUN  99     No
```

Comment: Please check required output in my post. that is  the expected outcome

Comment: What is the expected behavior for missing data (gaps, less than 3 data rows per group)?

Answer (score 4):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(-as.IDate(DATE, "%m/%d/%Y"), toupper(DAY))
     ][HolidayWeek=="No",.(Ave = sum(Hits[1:3])/.N) , by = .(DAY=toupper(DAY))]
#  DAY      Ave
#1: SAT 31.66667
#2: FRI 39.33333
#3: THU 47.66667
#4: WED 70.00000
#5: TUE 41.00000
#6: MON 39.33333
#7: SUN 34.33333
```

If it is the average of the 3 'Hits'

```
setDT(df1)[order(-as.IDate(DATE, "%m/%d/%Y"), toupper(DAY))
 ][HolidayWeek=="No",.(Ave = mean(Hits[1:3])) , by = .(DAY=toupper(DAY))]
```

Comment: I think the avg of the last three data rows per group is requested. Dividing by `.N` could end up in a wrong avg in case of more than three existing rows for a group. `min(.N,3)`?

Comment: @RYoda  In that case, we can just do `(Ave  = mean(Hits[1:3]))`

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Holiday_Week == 'No', .(Avg = sum(head(Hits, 3))/.N), by = .(CAT, DAY = tolower(DAY))]

#   CAT DAY      Avg
#1:   A sat 31.66667
#2:   A fri 39.33333
#3:   A thu 47.66667
#4:   A wed 70.00000
#5:   A tue 41.00000
#6:   A mon 39.33333
#7:   A sun 34.33333
```

Comment: it doesnt seem average of last 3.

Comment: In which part you are limiting the weeks that will be averaged? I just couldn't see.

Comment: Yes but what if data is longer than given in the question?

Comment: I mean if there is 5 weeks, then your code will take average of all those 5 weeks' unique days, wont it?

Comment: Hi- The code above is simply taking mean of all available data, it should take mean of last 3 weekdays excluding holiday weeks . For each category , I have more than 50 weeks of data and i have 100+ categories ( like A,B,C ....). How can we achieve the mean for the last 3 weekdays for each category

Comment: Dividing by `.N` for calculating the avg looks strange, since the avg or the last 3 days is wanted (not of all available non-holiday days). Using `3` as constant could be a solution but in case of less than three available data rows for a group the result is still wrong. `min(.N, 3)` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

answer <- x %>% filter(Holiday=="No") %>% group_by(Day)  %>% 
top_n(3,desc(Date))  %>% summarise(Avg = sum(Hits)/n())
```

It removes all Holiday's, then for every 'DAY' it then takes the last three dates for each of those days and finally summarizes the number of hits and divide by the number of those days, giving you the average.

Please note your 'days' of week aren't all Uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

A base `R` solution

```
do.call("rbind",
        lapply(split(df,df[,c("Holiday","CAT","DAY")]),
               function(x) if (x$Holiday[1]=="Yes") {
                 NULL
               } else {
                 data.frame(CAT=x$CAT[1],
                            DAY=x$DAY[1],
                            MN=mean(tail(x[order(x$DATE),],3)$Hits))}))
#         CAT DAY       MN
#No.A.FRI   A FRI 39.33333
#No.A.MON   A MON 39.33333
#No.A.SAT   A SAT 31.66667
#No.A.SUN   A SUN 34.33333
#No.A.THU   A THU 47.66667
#No.A.TUE   A TUE 41.00000
#No.A.WED   A WED 70.00000
```

Comment: BTW: I have manually changed `Sat` to `SAT` in your sample data, as I have assumed this is just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Average by day split for non holidays and holidays

```
Library(data.table)

data <- Input data

setDT(data)[, mean(Hits), by = .(DAY, Holiday) ]
```

Perhaps use `tolower(DAY)` as there are some naming differences in your data.

For just no holiday:

```
setDT(data)[Holiday == "No", mean(Hits), by = tolower(DAY) ]
```